# In Knockout.js, how to sort viewModel item based on checkbox field after mapping

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, javascript-framework

Data example, where `VoucherRedeemed` is a `checkbox` value:

```
{
 VoucherTitle: "title 2",
 VoucherRedeemed: false,
},{
 VoucherTitle: "title 4",
 VoucherRedeemed: true,
},{
 VoucherTitle: "title 6",
 VoucherRedeemed: false,
},{
 VoucherTitle: "title 9",
 VoucherRedeemed: true,
}
```

How do I sort the viewModel.voucher based on the checkbox value, after mapping:

```
viewModel.voucher = ko.mapping.fromJS(voucherData.voucher)
```

I've had a look at sorting observable arrays, but did not manage to tie up to the mapping scenario for checkbox value sorting. (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Any example of how to sort an array after ko.mapping.fromJS will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured.

Sort the voucherData before mapping it into the viewModel. Once it is in the viewModel, not sure if it is possible or easy to do any sorting.

Answer (score 6):

You can sort once you have populated the view model.

Have a look at the fiddle I have put together here [Knockout Sort Example](http://jsfiddle.net/maurice_butler/vy9SR/)

You need to call the sort method on the observable passing in a function to sort on the property you want.

Comment: ahh... true is gt false. didn't know that!

Comment: after ko.applyBindings, how can the list be re-ordered once the checkbox value changes on checked?

Comment: Yes in Javascript true and false can be coerced to the integer values 1 and 0 respectivly. Therefore 1 > 0.

To re-sort once the list has been changed / checkbox changed you can just call the sort method, passing the sorting function again

If you are using a method to add / update the changes you can add this call in there.